# Parsing data from javascript var to php , and writing back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, parsing

I am trying to achieve the following results and i was wondering if someone can guide me along or point me in the right direction.

1) I have managed to parse the data out for my variable.js file as you can see from the code below. However the image does not get through.
(*Any idea if it could be done or what was done wrongly ?*)

2) Writing/editing the data from a html form back into the variable.js file
(How do I do a write back function into the **variable.js** ?)

**I apologies if this is rather confusing. What i meant by external file was simply the content is not to be inserted into the html file itself and to be extracted from else where. What i did by myself was to as below.

Many Thanks.

Below are some of the codes i am using

**html**

// Assigning data from their respective variables **index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/auction.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="auctionItemTemplate">
<div class="AuctionContainer">
    <div class="ItemTitle">${name}</div>
    <div class="DealImage">${dealimage}</div>
    <div class="Countdown">${countdown}</div>
    <div class="Price">${price}</div>
    <div class="Location">${location}</div>
    <div class="Description">${description}</div>   
</div>  

//displaying of details

<div id="AuctionList1"></div>
```

//Dynamic data from a external Javascript file named **Variables.JS**

```
    var data = [
        {name: "Title 1", price:"$100", countdown: "April 2, 2014 15:41:00", location:"Brisbane", description:"awesome stuff", highestBidder: "Highest bidder 1" , dealimage: "\images\banner_color.jpg"},
    ];
```

// I have an auction timer javascript in this file which append the data back to the html side named **auction.js**

```
$('#auctionItemTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#AuctionList');
```

Comment: **1.** You seem to ask 2 questions. Try to disentangle them into the 2 smaller problems and ask them separately **2.** Define your use of "external"... Does it mean other domain, other file or other server... something else entirely....

Comment: Hi Chris, i guess you are right. It is indeed confusing. I have managed to parse the data out for my variable.js file as you can see from the code above. However the image does not get through.

Also i am unsure of writing/editing the data from a html form back into the variable.js file

Comment: _“However the image does not get through.”_ – and why exactly would you expect `<div class="DealImage">\images\banner_color.jpg</div>` to display an image …? How would you _normally_ embed an image into an HTML document – would you _maybe, perhaps_ be using something like `<img src="path-goes-here">`? Then what made you think this would work _any different_ here? (Btw., you should use forward slashes in web paths, so `/` instead of \.)

Comment: @CBroe I actually thought it would work. I tired putting '<img src="D:/xampp/htdocs/Pratical 3/images/banner_color.jpg"/>' into the variable too. What do you suggest i should be trying ?

Comment: First of all you should check whether your templating engine is even supposed to work that way – or if it is only supposed to replace _text_ placeholders, and not attribute values as well.